# 3 switches for 2 lights split into 2 switches per light

Tags: switch, light

We have a center-entry hall way with a light at each end. There are three 3-way switches. One in the middle, and one at each end. All three switches control both lights at the same time. We want to split the center switch into two so that the switches at each end and one of the center switches control ONLY the light for that end of the hallway.

Switch A----Light 1-----Switch B----Light 2---- Switch C is what we have.

Switch A----Light 1----Switch B / Switch D----Light 2----Switch C is what we want.

How do we split Switch B into B & D?

Comment: This may be easy, hard or (short of running new cables) nearly impossible. Smart switches may be a solution. **Please upload a picture showing all the wires going to each switch.** Do not disconnect any wires - just turn off the breaker and unscrew each switch from the box and pull out the switch and take pictures.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all the boxes involved please?

Comment: You might find the the middle switch is a 4-way.

Comment: If you're A-OK with busting out the drywall and running all new cables, please say that.  Otherwise we assume you want to avoid that, and make best use of the existing wiring. We'll need to know/see what that is; *we can't infer your wiring from your description* because there are several ways to do what  you describe (some illegal).

Comment: If someone can tell me how to upload photos, I'll gladly do that. I cannot find how.

Comment: Edit your question and there should be a "mountains and sun" icon. You can upload files directly from your computer or upload elsewhere and paste a link. Sorry it isn't a super-intuitive system and no way to email the pictures in (I've written systems that work that way, but I can't change StackExchange).

Comment: Looks like I'm out of luck on this forum. My camera is set at the lowest photo size and they're too big to upload here. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Your photo viewing software may be able to export your pictures to a smaller size.

Comment: While not Home Improvement:  There are many apps that can substantially compress pictures,   I use: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saawanapps.photocompress&hl=en_US&gl=US

But there are many others.   I use it all the time before downloading pics to my PC to save space on my PC as well as reduce download time.   Works great.

Comment: Try uploading to your photo-sharing site of choice (imgur works well and doesn't have a burdensome signup process) and then [edit] your question to add links to the photos.

Comment: You camera may be able to use a different file type like JPEG to bring the file size down further.  Otherwise, GIMP is free and very capable.  Memory size has become so large that cameras don't necessarily default to a compressed format.  To convert with GIMP, just load the file, use crop or scale image to reduce actual dimensions and use "Export as" to save it as a JPEG.  2 Mb file limit on SE gives you roughly 4 Mpixels in a JPEG to work with, so roughly a 2000 x 2000 image, which is quite large.  I'd recommend aiming for 1000 x 1000 unless you need the extra resolution.